# Search for multiple phone number formats in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I got a database with a user table. This table contains a column `phonenumber`. The problem is that its fields use multiple number patterns.

The current patterns I found:

- 06403/975-0
- +496403975 0
- 06403 975-0
- 06403 975 0
- +49 6403 975 0

When searching for a user in the database, is there a way to search for all number patterns?

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE phone = '0123456789'
```

I use Oracle and MS SQL

Comment: This question is not clear what you are trying to do. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: You say you use both Oracle and SQL Server, but what DBMS is the data actually in? I find it surprising you'll duplicating it across the 2.

Comment: You can use LIKE in SQL Server to do wildcards (check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page for examples of arguments). I think the real answer here, though, is to clean the data and possibly create some constraints and/or modify the application to validate the format before insert.

Comment: Do you mean, the stored phone number should match the input value, AFTER removing all the non-digit characters from the stored phone number? That is easy to do, even with standard string functions (no need for regular expressions; surely there will be some answers with regular expressions...) But you do need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your question means this:

"Is it possible to remove all the non-digit characters from the stored phone number, before making the comparison in the `WHERE` clause?"

a possible solution looks like this:

```
... 
where translate(phone, '0123456789' || phone, '0123456789') = <input value here>
```

`TRANSLATE` will translate every digit to itself, and all other characters in `phone` to nothing (they will simply be deleted from the string). This is exactly what you want.

If you find that the query is slow, you may want to create a (function-based) index on  `translate(phone, '0123456789' || phone, '0123456789')`.

**EDIT**: I missed the part where you said you are using both Oracle and SQL Server. I did a quick search and found that SQL Server does not have a function similar to Oracle's `TRANSLATE`. I will leave it to SQL Server experts to help you with that part; I don't know SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you could do it like this. Strip out the non-numeric characters with `translate()` to get the phone number. You need to handle the leading zero or international dialling code:

```
select username from your_table
where translate(phone, '1234567890+/ -', '1234567890') in ('064039750', '4964039750')
```

You may need to tweak this if you don't know what the  international dialling code is.

Obviously the actual problem is one of data quality: the application should enforce a strict format on phone numbers. One bout of data cleansing on write saves a whole bunch of grief on read.

Comment: Note that you don't need to know beforehand what non-digit characters may have to be removed. I showed how in my Answer.

Comment: ...and in fact if you knew all the non-digit symbols beforehand, you could use a simpler `translate`, for example `translate(phone, '0+/ -', '0')`.

Comment: +1 totally agree with cleaning data first, then insert.  Store the raw value, but also store the clean value that can be used for lookups, display, joins, etc.

Comment: @tbone - that would violate third normal form. What if an update is made, where one value is changed but not the other? Now you have contradictory values in the data. Better options: (1) a virtual (calculated) column; (2) a function-based index; (3) a VIEW where that calculation is made (perhaps a materialized view if speed is critical).

Comment: @mathguy In a real world data company, there will probably be calls to a separate cleaning service that will use complicated logic to "clean" certain fields.  Consider cleaning address fields where 3rd party libraries (and/or cloud services) are called, in addition to many layers of internal business logic.  Phone numbers are a simplified example, but can still contain quite a bit of logic to clean properly.  Its beyond the scope of cleaning up on the fly inside a query

Comment: @tbone - That still doesn't make it right to store both the raw string and the digits-only cleansed string. In my company (I never worked in IT but I know what we were doing), since we had to deal with many phone formats, we would store both a FORMAT MODEL column and a "pure digits" column, with a constraint that the digits had to be exactly the right count to fit the model. You do need to store the format model for various input and output purposes. But it makes no sense to store the FORMATTED NUMBER in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You have a database containing phone numbers. These are sometimes in international format, but often in some national format, probably German, where two leading zeros introduce a country code, while a single leading zero would introduce an area code instead (assuming the home country Germany then). Moreover, a phone number can contain symbols for readability, namely `'-'`, `'/'`, and `' '`.

So

- +49 12/3456-7 means +491234567 of course
- 00441234567 means +441234567
- 04412345 means +494412345

I suggest you convert all numbers into international format in these steps:

1. replace a leading `+` with a leading `00`, thus making only digits important
2. remove every character that is not a digit
3. replace a leading `00` with a leading `+`
4. replace a leading `0` with a leading `+49`

Use Oracle's `REGEXP_REPLACE` for this:

```
select 
  regexp_replace( 
    regexp_replace(
      regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(trim(phone),
          '^\+', '00'), -- leading '+' -> leading '00'
        '[^[:digit:]]', ''), -- remove all non-digits
      '^00' , '+'), -- leading '00' -> leading '+'
    '^0', '+49') -- leading '0' -> leading '+49'
  as international_phone
from mytable;
```

You can do this in the `WHERE` clause of course:

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE regexp_replace(...) = '+49123456789'
```

or even

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE regexp_replace(...phone...) = regexp_replace(...'0123456789'...)
```

And you may write a PL/SQL function for this for convenience and use it so:

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE international_phone(phone) = international_phone('0123456789')
```

This is for Oracle. There may be something alike for SQL Server.