# oracle regex functions to format us phone numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to format us phone numbers using Oracle regular expression.

I have to use below conditions

1. if count of digits < 10 then null
2. if count of digits = 10 then format the phone number as 111-111-1111
3. if count of digits > 10 and has a plus sign at the front then format the 
    digits by skipping first digit after plus sign as 111-111-1111
4. if count of digits > 10 and has no plus sign at the front then format the first 10 digits as 111-111-1111

See examples below for all 4 cases

```
+(555)                     --> NULL
1112223333                 --> 111-222-3333
+1 (123) 1111111 x1111     --> 123-111-1111
(111)1111111 Ext. 1111     --> 111-111-1111
(111) 111-1111 ext 1111    --> 111-111-1111                 
2 111-111-1111             --> 211-111-1111
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, don't ask multiple questions at once. Surely, you can handle some, and probably most, of these conditions yourself. Try to concentrate on a single condition that is problematic.

Comment: It is not clear what your exact problem is. Don't you know how to select data from a table? Don't you know how to apply string functions? Do you think you need a certain function, but you dont know whether such exists and you don't know where to look this up? Anything else? When reporting a problem you should always tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this (without regular expressions):

1. Strip out the non-digit characters with `translate()`
2. Reduce to ten digits with `substr()`
3. Re-format with `substr()`

So:

```
 with cte as 
    ( select substr ( 
                translate ( phone
                            , '1234567890' || phone
                            , '1234567890' 
                    ) , 1, 10 ) as clean_phone 
      from your_table 
    )
 select  case 
             when length(clean_phone) = 10 then
                 substr(clean_phone, 1, 3)
                 ||'-'||
                 substr(clean_phone, 4, 4)
                 ||'-'||
                 substr(clean_phone, 7, 4)
             else null end as fmt_phone
 from cte
```

Tip of the hat to [@mathguy for the `translate()` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51989091/146325).

Answer (score 0):

I used a nested SQL.
In the innermost step, tried to get rid of digit after plus sign and all non-numeric characters by using `regexp_replace` and `substr`,

and then converted to the desired format by using `format model` as argument of *to_char* function as below :

```
select (case when length(str_)<10 then null
         else
         replace(to_char(substr(str_,1,10),'fm999,999,9999'),',','-')
         end)
         as str
    from 
     (
      select (case when substr(str,1,1)='+' then
              regexp_replace(substr(str,3,length(str)),'[^0-9]','')
              else
              regexp_replace(str,'[^0-9]','') 
              end) as str_
       from tab
     );
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e657d/45)

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_REPLACE(phone,'^(+?1[.[:space:]-])?(?(\d{3})(\d*).*','\2-\3')